Choose bar column position in Vega Bar chart
I have a rendering issue with Vega. Here is a link to my exemple
The issue is that I want to display the 'general' (in yellow) bar at the left of the others
In the exemple, you can search for this object :
{
    "x": 1716422400000,
    "y": "0.8",
    "c": "data 1",
    "column": 1,
    "position": 0
}

If you set the 'column' property to 2 (to put it at the right, since the Yellow one 'general' is set to 1) all the bars will go on the left and the 'general' goes to the right
Is there any solution ? Am I missing a property ?
Thank you in advance ^^
